# mysql database value as select id

Tags: php, html, mysql

I am trying to assign an ID to values to be posted with the submit tag

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM `events`";
$result2 = mysqli_query($connect, $query);

$options = "";
while($row2 = mysqli_fetch_array($result2))
{
    $options = $options."<option>$row2[1] $row2[2]</option>";
}
```

---

```
<select>
    <?php echo $options;?>
</select>
```

Doing this outputs the event name and the date it will take place ( 2nd and 3rd item in my mysql database. This later gets used in a form and lists these as options for someone to pick. I was wondering if there was a way to add a proper value= to them. The first thing in my mysql database is a random generated ID for each "event" but I can't figure out how to echo the id of each event in the option tag without it breaking.

Comment: without breaking means what?

Comment: If the first element is id, $row2[0] will contain it.

Comment: What you're asking is really quite basic. So basic in fact, that I'm struggling to think of what the issue might be. You should include your attempt to put the `value` in the `<option>` so we can help you

Comment: @Sameera Everything I've attempted has made it stop working

Comment: @Phil I know it is the value tag, but when you try to run the code with adding the value tag it stops working because it's a mysql callback I think. not really sure why it breaks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, when using positional results (ie `$row2[0]`, `$row2[1]`, etc), you should be explicit in your `SELECT` query to guarantee order, ie

```
SELECT `ID`, `name`, `date` FROM `events`
```

---

Really all you need is to interpolate whatever dynamic values you need into the HTML string.

It's best to use something like `htmlspecialchars()` in these cases to avoid issues with markup. For example

```
while($row2 = mysqli_fetch_array($result2)) {
    $options .= vsprintf('<option value="%s">%s %s</option>',
        array_map('htmlspecialchars', $row2));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$options .= $options.'<option value="'.htmlspecialchars($id).'">'.htmlspecialchars($event).'</option>';
```

I think your answer is this.

Comment: Where do `$id` and `$event` come from?

Comment: `$id` is your event id and `$event` is your event

Comment: Yes, but they're not defined in OP's code or yours so this answer doesn't really make sense

Answer (score 0):

Although Phil's way is probably proper. I don't know how I didn't try

```
"<option value=$row2[0]>$row2[1] $row2[2]</option>"
```

removing the extra `"` that I had around `$row2[0]` made it work.

Comment: This could easily break if your `value` ever contained spaces

Comment: My value is a auto generated ID

Comment: My comment was more a word-of-warning. HTML attributes are best quoted in all circumstances

Answer (score -1):

```
$options = $options."<option value="."$row2[0]".">$row2[1] $row2[2]</option>";
```

This is very simple.

Comment: Why the mix of concatenation and interpolation?

Comment: Well, for some values it would *"work"* but not for others. In regards to my first question though, this answer is equivalent to `"<option value=$row2[0]>$row2[1] $row2[2]</option>"`. It's not clear why you're using concatenation at all